# Okta API getting started error setting cert type | Getting User Apps api call

Tags: api, curl, ssl, saml-2.0

I am trying to get started with the Okta API.

The command I type in cmd is:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: SSWS MyAPITokenHERE" \
        -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -X GET "https://MyDomain.okta.com/api/v1/apps"
```

*note I formatted with backslashes at the end of line to better read.

The above command is the format according to the API documents.

```
C:\Users\MyAccount>curl -v -H "Authorization: SSWS MyApiToken" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X
 GET "https://MyDomain.okta.com/api/v1/apps" --cert-type (SSL)

* About to connect() to mydomain.okta.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 99.99.999.999...
* connected
* Connected to mydomain.okta.com (99.99.999.999) port 443 (#0)
* error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Closing connection #0
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

I have tried setting the certification type to SSL but that did not fix it. I am currently going through documentation and stackoverflow questions but with no luck.

I would appreciate it if someone can explain the reasoning behind this & help me figure out what I need to do? Thank you in advance.

**Okta API Documentation**
https://github.com/okta/api/blob/master/docs/getting_started/design_principles.md

**CURL Documentation**
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

**Update**
I have added the optional parameter  [-k] to suppress the SSL check but still would like to know what the problem could is

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: SSWS MyAPITokenHERE" \
        -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -X GET "https://MyDomain.okta.com/api/v1/apps" -k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also add the `-k` parameter with your curl command to overcome this ssl error by ignoring the ssl verification.

Answer (score 0):

Curl needs to know/trust the certificate used to sign the certificate from Okta.  As you are using curl, this certificate should be in the file `/usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt` *(and this file needs to be readable by the user which is running the curl command)*.  You can download a current copy of the bundle (which includes the cert you need) from the [Curl Cert Authority Bundle](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) webpage.